# Can I use php to update an outdated script with a ZIP packed script from an external domain?

Tags: php

I am writing a script and I was looking into providing some sort of a tool that updates the script when the client requests.

Project is simple logic.

1. Client server sends a request to mother server (which stores the updated scripts in ZIP files) and downloads the .ZIP file from the server.
2. Client server receives the .ZIP file and unpacks it overwriting the outdated script files.

Can someone give me a basic guide or what do I need to do to implement such function ?

I can use pclzip to create/extract archives but I do not know where to start.

Thanks for any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use ftp(using php) to upload

example in joomla we can do the following :

```
jimport('joomla.client.ftp');
$ftp = JFTP::getInstance($server['ip'], 21, null, $server['user'], $server['password']);

try {
foreach($files as $file) {
$fullpath = JPATH_SITE . $file;
$this->createdirs($ftp, $rootdir . $file);
if($ftp->store($fullpath, $rootdir . $file) == false) {
  throw new Exception("Cannot transfer file " . $file);
 }
  } 
foreach($adminfiles as $file) {
 $fullpath = JPATH_SITE . $file;
 $this->createdirs($ftp, $rootdir . $file);  
  if($ftp->store($fullpath, $rootdir . $file) == false) {
 throw new Exception("Cannot transfer file " . $file);
}
 }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
$ftp->quit();  
die($e->getMessage());
}
$ftp->quit();
```

Comment: it was just an example , you need a ftp library to do what u want to do